# compare two columns in R

Tags: r, function

I have two columns in R, they are columns of 1's and 0's.

```
  Score Predict
     1       1
     1       0
     0       1
     1       1
     0       1
     1       0
     1       1
     1       1
     1       1
     0       1
     0       0
     0       0
     0       0
     1       1
     1       1
     1       1
```

I need to write a function that compares each column and gets an average of how many times the predicted column is the same as the score column. This shouldn't be too difficult but I am new with 'R' coding so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `mean(Score == Predict)`

Comment: wow, should of got that one. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Comment to answer:

> compares each column...  predicted column is the same as the score column

```
Score == Predict # or with(df, Score == Predict)
```

> and gets an average

```
mean(Score == Predict) # with(df, Score == Predict)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data is

```
 set.seed(123)
 df <- data.frame(a = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5), b = rbinom(10, 1, 0.75) )
```

Then

```
sum(df$a == df$b)/nrow(df) 
[1] 0.9
```

Comment: @Gregor - sorry I can't comment yet inline. I think I submitted this just after your answer. There is no real benefit to not using mean in this case that I see.

Answer (score 0):

```
bdf <- data.frame(Score = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5), Predict = rbinom(10, 1, 0.5))
sum(with(bdf, Score == Predict))/nrow(bdf)
```

Comment: How is this different than @Jesse Raab's answer? (And to both of you, why would you prefer `sum()/nrow()` instead of `mean()`?)

Comment: OP is a new R user - this shows the use of with, column naming, and provides a complete example.